# When is the exp bonus applied for seasonal armour pieces?

Tags: destiny-2

The game often has themed armour items which have a seasonal exp bonus perk on them. For the current season (Season of the Seraph) it is the following.

[image: Seraph Sensor Array - Grants 5% reputation gains with the Exo Frame]

When does this bonus get applied? Can I complete all the Exo Frame bounties, swap armour and then hand them in to get the bonus exp? Or do I need to wear the armour throughout the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, whenever you are wearing the armour and gain reputation, the bonus applies. So, when you turn in a bounty or complete an activity with the armour on, you get bonus reputation and without it on, you won't.